# Proving $\left.\frac{\partial H}{\partial P }\right|_T = V - T\left.\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right|_P$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I have a derivation of

$$\left.\frac{\partial H}{\partial P }\right|_T  = V - T\left.\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right|_P$$

that makes use of $S$ and $G$.

Here it is succinctly

$$dG = VdP - SdT$$

$$\left.\frac{\partial V}{\partial T }\right|_P  = -\left.\frac{\partial S}{\partial P}\right|_T$$

$$dS = \left. \frac{\partial S}{\partial P}\right|_T dP + \left.\frac{\partial S}{\partial T }\right|_P dT $$

$$dS = \left. \frac{\partial S}{\partial P}\right|_T dP - \left.\frac{\partial V}{\partial T }\right|_P dT $$

$$dH = TdS + VdP $$

$$dH = T \left.\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right|_P  dT + \left(V - T\left.\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right|_P\right) dP $$

$$\left.\frac{\partial H}{\partial P }\right|_T  = V - T\left.\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right|_P$$

Is there a simpler way to prove this that is not based on $G$ and $S$?

Comment: The derivation contains an error; the second-to-last line should be $dH = T \left.\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right|_P  dT + \left(V - T\left.\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right|_P\right) dP$.

Comment: Yes, I corrected the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you rely on a [lookup table](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/25018/6/TOE05.pdf) to obtain a thermodynamic relation. Referring to that table, we soon obtain

$$\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial P }\right)_T =V(1-\alpha T),$$ as desired, where the volumetric thermal expansion coefficient $\alpha=1/V(\partial V/\partial T)_P$. It's hardly a proof to simply look something up, though.

We could have also started by applying $H=U+PV$ and differentiating with respect to $P$ at constant $T$:

$$\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial P }\right)_T =\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial P }\right)_T+V+P\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial P }\right)_T.\tag{1}$$

From the same table, $$\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial P }\right)_T=\frac{PV}{K_T}-V\alpha T,$$

where the isothermal bulk modulus $K_T=-V(\partial P/\partial V)_T$. This reduces to the same result. Again, though, you might consider the use of the table to be "cheating."

To my knowledge, fully deriving the expressions shown in the lookup table requires referring to $S$ and $G$. For example, as a slight alternative to your definition above, if we recall that $dU+P\,dV=T\,dS$, then Eq. (1) above becomes

$$\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial P }\right)_T =T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial P }\right)_T+V,$$

and if we note that $(\partial S/\partial P)_T=-(\partial G/\partial T\partial P)_T=-(\partial G/\partial P\partial T)_P=-(\partial V/\partial T)_P$, then we obtain the same result.